# How to update the max record in field

Tags: ms-access-2007

my table is

sh_name    |     sh_count  |  shoba
1          |           3     |    1
2          |         7     |    1
3          |         2     |    1
1          |         6     |    2
2          |         5     |    2
**3**          |         3     |    2

i want to update the max record in field sh_name from 3 to 11 in shoba 2
i use this code but not work

UPDATE sheet  SET sh_count = 11  where    sh_name = (select max(sh_name)  from sheet where shoba = 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update the one row you need to repeat the `shoba = 2` condition like so:

```sql
UPDATE sheet SET sh_count = 11 
WHERE sh_name = (SELECT MAX(sh_name) FROM sheet WHERE shoba = 2)
    AND shoba = 2
```